# Pop up alert in a javascript if

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>


<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Item not found</p>
</div>


<script>
var number = 1;

if (number == 1) {
    alert('In here');
}
</script>
```

However I want to make the pop up done in jquery run inside the if and remove the alert. I have tried innerHTML to no luck is this something that  can be done.

Comment: To remove the alert, remove the alert `alert('In here');`

Comment: Replace the alert with ` $( "#dialog" ).dialog();`.. a bit confused as to what you're asking

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line `alert('In here');` and place the line `$( "#dialog" ).dialog();` in the if-statement. That code block should then be placed in the jQuery document load event:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
      var number = 1;

      if (number === 1) {
          $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
      }
  });
  </script>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Item not found</p>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Or, just the code in the script block (not using the jQuery load event):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Item not found</p>
</div>

<script>
var number = 1;

if (number === 1) {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding what you're asking: the jQuery `dialog` object includes a "close" method, which you can use if you want to close the dialog without user intervention:

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close

```js
$("#dialog").dialog();

$('#hideit').on('click', function() { // button added for demo purposes
  $('#dialog').dialog("close") // This is what you would put in your "IF" statement
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Item not found</p>
</div>

<button id="hideit">hide</button>
```